# How to disconnect iCloud from my MacBook?

Tags: macos, desktop, icloud

This all started with the system prompting an update on my current macOS Mojave version 10.14.3. When I wanted to go and update the system, I discovered that iCloud Drive takes up 50 GB on my mac.

I went to System Preferences -> iCloud -> iCloud Drive -> options -> unchecked the box for desktop and suddenly everything on my desktop disappeared, I checked it again to bring back all the stuff then I went to System Preferences -> iCloud -> iCloud Drive -> unchecked the box -> keep a copy and waited for 7 hours... there was no progress so I clicked on turn off and everything on my desktop disappeared again.

so, how do I get rid of iCloud without messing up my desktop?